# am using postman to make a post request to an API and i receive json response , when i try to make the post request , i receive string response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
  public async Task <JObject> PostOcr1()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://microsoft-computer-vision3.p.rapidapi.com/ocr?detectOrientation=true&language=ar"),
            Headers =
{
    { "x-rapidapi-key", "8830b90506msha145d86eb92ef41p16ff4djsn74eca27d491" },
    { "x-rapidapi-host", "microsoft-computer-vision3.p.rapidapi.com" },
},
            Content = new StringContent("{\r\n    \"url\": \"https://scontent.fcai19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.18169-9/14040173_1167189816673874_4131574684799363249_n.png?_nc_cat=102&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=973b4a&_nc_ohc=Ovfjjq2erC4AX-r8M5k&_nc_ht=scontent.fcai19-1.fna&oh=7d8d425c6cbcbef95cc820e45fa158f3&oe=60A167BA\"\r\n}")
            //   Content = new StringContent("{\r\n    \"url\": \"https://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/15430864595779441.jpg\"\r\n}")

            {
                Headers =
    {
        ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
    }
            }
        };
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
              var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(body);
            
            return body;
        }
    }
```

i dont want the response to be converted to string
i think the problem is in that line.
var body = await response.Content.**ReadAsStringAsync();**

is there a way to get the same response as the postman (json)

Comment: But json is a string =)

Comment: You are parsing to a JObject ,but ignore that and return the string body

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error? You are reading response as a string "response.Contenet.ReadAsStringAsync()" and turning it into a JObject. You are already getting application/json. So just make a JObject = response.content, I think. This is somewhat of an un orthodox way to consume http requests. Normally you would deserialize the response into a cs object. Reading up on that and REST API would help you to understand what's going on a bit better.